# Equivalent of AddFolderApplicationModelConvention for MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to make generic controller in **ASP .NET Core 5** project. For this I try to use `IControllerModelConvention` because of I successed with `IPageApplicationModelConvention`. In my application I can create generic razor pages.

This code for generic controller:

```
public class GenericControllerConfigureOptions<TEntity> : IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions> where TEntity : class {
    public void PostConfigure(string name, MvcOptions options) {
        name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        var convention = new GenericControllerConvention<TEntity>();
        options.Conventions.Add(convention);
    }
}

public class GenericControllerConvention<TEntity> : IControllerModelConvention where TEntity : class {
    public void Apply(ControllerModel model) {
        var defaultUIAttribute = model.ControllerType.GetCustomAttribute<GenericControllerAttribute>();
        if (defaultUIAttribute == null) {
            return;
        }

        ValidateTemplate(defaultUIAttribute.Template);
        var templateInstance = defaultUIAttribute.Template.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity));
        model.ControllerName = templateInstance.Name;
    }

    private void ValidateTemplate(Type template) {
        if (template.IsAbstract || !template.IsGenericTypeDefinition) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Implementation type can't be abstract or non generic.");
        }
        var genericArguments = template.GetGenericArguments();
        if (genericArguments.Length != 1) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Implementation type contains wrong generic arity.");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is working part for generic razor pages.

```
public class GenericPageModelConvention<TEntity> : IPageApplicationModelConvention where TEntity : class {
    public void Apply(PageApplicationModel model) {
        var defaultUIAttribute = model.ModelType.GetCustomAttribute<GenericPageAttribute>();
        if (defaultUIAttribute == null) {
            return;
        }

        ValidateTemplate(defaultUIAttribute.Template);
        var templateInstance = defaultUIAttribute.Template.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity));
        model.ModelType = templateInstance.GetTypeInfo();
    }

    private void ValidateTemplate(Type template) {
        if (template.IsAbstract || !template.IsGenericTypeDefinition) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Implementation type can't be abstract or non generic.");
        }
        var genericArguments = template.GetGenericArguments();
        if (genericArguments.Length != 1) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Implementation type contains wrong generic arity.");
        }
    }
}

public class GenericPageConfigureOptions<TEntity> : IPostConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions> where TEntity : class {
    public void PostConfigure(string name, RazorPagesOptions options) {
        name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        var convention = new GenericPageModelConvention<TEntity>();
        options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention("/", pam => convention.Apply(pam));
    }
}
```

My problem is start in IPostConfigureOptions implementation. In MVC project only HomeController hit here. I cannot give any folder for this.

```
//This is mvc
var convention = new GenericControllerConvention<TEntity>();
options.Conventions.Add(convention);
//This is razor pages
var convention = new GenericPageModelConvention<TEntity>();
options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention("/", pam => convention.Apply(pam));
```

What is the equivalent of `AddFolderApplicationModelConvention` for MVC Controller?

Comment: it's a bit unclear when you say *only HomeController hit here* - the controller model convention should target all controllers. And of course it's not an equivalent for something like folder model convention. Here I understand the requirement that when accessing any controllers ***in a folder***, some convention must be applied. But you did not talk about that folder as well, or you mean the root folder (which is like `"/"`)?

Comment: I have 2 controller Home and Test. After app started, in debug, I catch only _HomeController_ in this class. I try to access all controller in root folder. So I use `"/"` in razor pages.

Comment: Controllers and Razor pages are two completely separate and distinctive concepts that do not allow you to mix them like that. You cannot expect controllers to work in folders, just like you cannot expect Razor pages to have custom routes or actions.

Comment: @poke Yes you are right, they are different however controllers are still inside a folder, root or inside another one.

Comment: Controllers are *classes* in the first place, and as such they are compiled into the assembly just like any other class in the project in any other folder. The compiled binary has no concept of in what folder the file originally was. – When you add a Razor pages convention, then the path there refers to the *route* and that route is—by convention—the path to the Razor page. That concept does not apply to controllers though.

Comment: the concept of folder & directories is actually for projects (at design-time), organized by VS. That is mapped fairly well with razor pages by convention. But there is not such similar thing for controllers. I can imagine how it can be complicated when a file contains several controller classes :) - Actually I think it's possible to build that convention by yourself, initially when starting the app, you load the physical files, parse the file content for controller names ... (easier if each file is a controller, ends with `Controller`, ...).

Comment: @poke I understand concept. Also PageModels are classes. Route is working different but still working for controller. In my quesiton, I am not comparing them. I just do a working example with razor pages and I need to working one with controllers. If I am not using folder design, what I need to use? What's the correct way?

Comment: @is_oz the compiled output does not contain the directory info of classes, I think you need to somehow map that at the design time by convention, such as directories to namespaces. Or at least manually attach that info to each controller class by attributes, ...

Comment: Page models are classes, yes, but they actually don’t need to sit next to the Razor page’s `.cshtml`. The latter is _the_ Razor page and that’s what determines the route for that page. – That being said, there is no equivalent or similar concept with controllers. Usually, you apply filters to the controller and then have that filter apply to all that controller’s actions. That’s as close as you could get there.

Comment: @KingKing I use attributes, however that time, I am stuck when using Dependecy Injection. I have manager classes, and when trying to pass controller, I am getting again 404 Error.

Comment: @is_oz not sure if you get me right, I mean about attribute providing the mapped `folder` that you see at the design time :) - it's a bit tedious job. Your controller model convention then can base on that to determine the logic. Another option is somehow at design time (before deploying), you can run some ***custom*** VS extension to generate a config file (map file) which contains info about the map between folders (human's concept) and controllers (framework's concept). Initially at runtime, you load that config to build data for your processing.

Comment: @KingKing I get now. But I am not sure about it is true concept for generic controller :) Because I am not sure folder is good option. May be there is a better alternative or not. I just want to learn is there a equivalent of method.